# Tooltip for both tag and innertag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code is:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle clickme" href="#" data - original - title="Dimesion: Not available<br/>Status: QAED<br/>T'ber/QA: qa1<br/>Audio length: 00:00:05<br/>Images: 1" data - toggle="groupinfotooltip" data - container="body">Front0
        < span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle red pull-right " onmouseenter="showBlankTextAlert()" id="225_137_Front0_blank_alert" data - toggle="blankalerttooltip" data - original - title="One of audios text is blank" data - placement="right" style="padding:5px;">
            <\span>
                <\a>
```

If a Hover on `a` then it shows Dimension tooltip but when I hover on span then it will show both..so I hide main tooltip when user hover on `span`..What I want is If user hover on `a` then shows its tooltip and on `span` then shows its tooltip but in mine it shows both tooltip when I hover on `span`..I am using `mouseover` event.Any suggestion?

Comment: Please consider adding a working code snippet were people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: which tooltip you are using, any framework or default????

Comment: @MaheswaranS I am using bootstrap tooltip

Comment: @debin plz check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/egz0ufcx/2)

Comment: @Webruster I want tag withing tag tooltip..span is within a tag..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by separating them, because A tag is parent of SPAN in this case and whenever you enter SPAN you enter to A first.

See this fidle i prepared here:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/egz0ufcx/`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use stop propagation method for span element mouse enter event..then only the tooltip event not traverse to parent element. or

```js
$("span").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent("a").removeAttr("data-toggle");
});
```

Comment: then what if I reenter into a tag?